# Is it possible to have multiple names for a single complex type defined in a XSD?

Tags: xsd

I am creating an XSD where I defined a complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="TimeBasicComponents">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Hours" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Minutes" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Seconds" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="MilliSeconds" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I defined another complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="TimeOfDay">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="BasicComponents" type="TimeBasicComponents"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Zone" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now, I want to have another complex type for time duration. However, there is actually no need to define another complex type for this, it will be exactly same as "TimeBasicComponents". So, I was wondering if there is way to define multiple names for a single complex type in XSD?

-Sandeep

Comment: Why do you want a second name?  Why not just refer to the existing type?

Comment: Yeah, you could have two different elements that have the same complexType: `<xs:element name="Element1" type="myComplexType" />` and `<xs:element name="Element2" type="myComplexType" />`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to use `TimeBasicComponents` as a duration also? To my knowledge you can't have alias'es for a `complexType` but you can achieve something very similar using the `<xs:extension...` construct:

```
<xs:complexType name="TimeDuration">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="TimeBasicComponents" />
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

That way you will effectively have an alias without having to redefine the `TimeBasicComponents` complex-type.

Cheers,